# Is DB4O Replication faster than SQL Server Merge Replication?

Tags: replication, performance, db4o

Does the replication system that comes with [DB4O](http://www.db4o.com/) work well?  Basically I would like to know if anyone has some good numbers on the record throughput of their replication system and if it handles concurrency errors gracefully or not.  What is the relative performance difference between SQL Server's merge replication between two SQL servers and using DRS between two DB4O databases?

Comment: Sorry, never got deep into db4o replication. Did you try asking this in db4o forums at www.db4o.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are currently working on improving the replication system further and improving performance certainly is a goal.

I think it's quite hard to produce comparable figures. Every object that needs to be replicated requires a lookup in the UUID BTree. If you know what you are doing, you can finetune that to run completely in memory. Then again the throughput will depend very much on how many indexes you have on each side and how big indexes are. db4o and the SQL server of your choice (and any other SQL server) may scale differently with size and that may very much depend on the hardware you use (db4o loves solid state discs with short seek times).

This is like with any other benchmark: You can only find out how things really will work for you if you mock up the scenario that you think you need and run it on your hardware.

As to handling concurrency: Any conflict will call back into your code and it's your choice how you handle it. You can resolve by hand by merging changes to either side and you can also ignore objects. It's up to your code to find out what it thinks is right.

With respect to concurrency if you have a replication session running side-by-side with another live session that constantly modifies objects: Currently released dRS code is not yet strong for this case. While we implement replication between [db4o](http://www.db4o.com) and the high-end object database [Versant VOD](http://www.versant.com/en_US/products/) we will try to cover these kind of concurrency cases also.

Comment: Thanks Carl.  This is useful information.  My company is planning a big replication project to start in late august.  I'll do some benchmarks of my own and post them here.